# Firebase storing key only if it contains given data - javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to perform a if statement and only get the details from a key if a given value is present under the key field.

For example, given the below dataset

[image]

I want to search if the database 'jokes' contain text like 'HaHa', if it does, I want to make reference to the ID of that data set, in this case 'K9WJOahmsqmuPQbl8wD' and then perform a if statement only on the data under this ID.

for example,

```
var MyFirebase = data.val();
var keys = object.keys(MyFirebase); // This line gets all the keys in the table
// This loops through the keys
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){ 
    var key  = keys[i];
    var author = MyFirebase[key].author;
    var jokeText= MyFirebase[key].jokeText;
    var votes= MyFirebase[key].votes;

// Now I want to carry out a if statement, that checks if given text is inside that id

IF jokeText == "HAHA" && author == "test"
   getID = getParentID
     IF getID IS parent of "HAHA" && "test" 
        DOsomething
ELSE
  DOsomethingELSE

} // end for loop
```

I hope I have made myself clear, if not, please let me know :)

Comment: It's currently not possible to do a contains query in firebase realtime database. Or do you want to check if the value is equal or starts with that string?

Comment: What I want to achieve is, I want to get the parent id of the child if it contains a given string. I think equals could also work. so for example, IF jokeText == "HAHA" THEN get parentID of the child.